# Can't show "All Items" view in SPO page for a Calendar Events List

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created the Calendar List (Event List) and created a page to house the "All items" view...only to find that the "List" view app does not see my Calendar Event List , but does see "regular" lists. I tried embedding the URL for the "All Items" view in the Embed App, but it shows the whole page (See image) not the data in the view. I need it to show the "rows" in the SPO Page...and keep the "Sync with Outlook" functionality so I can't  just create a "standard" custom list.

Anyone got any ideas on how I can work around this in SPO? 
PS: I'd like to keep it as OOTB as possible due to the risk for breaking it with any upgrades down the line.
And I'm proficient in HTML but not in JavaScript or harder languages and the Admins of our Site Collection have blocked the use of SP Designer..

[image]

Comment: I've been thinking of working around the issue by creating a 2nd Custom list, and having the the Calendar list "copy" items to the Custom List. Then, I could just show the "All Items" view of the Custom List....but I'm not sure how to do that (the copy items when one is created or updated) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only OOB solution to inset a classic list view on a modern page is using the Embed web part, and it is not supported to show only the contents.

You might consider using **Focus on Content** feature in the web part so that it can hide some part of the ribbon.

Comment: Unfortunately this option is not available for us due to our businesses app filtering. Thanks for the suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may try with creating a custom list then in that create a **calendar view** then you can display this calendar view in your page.

You may refer the below article, how calendar view works in SharePoint :

[Share Point Calendar. Calendar in SharePoint. SharePoint Calendar Views](https://blog.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint-calendar-views/)

Comment: Unfortunately,  I have a requirement that the ability to sync the calendar doesn't allow that. The custom list doesn't allow that function. But thanks for commenting. :-)